# Rails: Auto-login already signed up user (Facebook/linkedin omniauth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, omniauth

I am using Omniauth and Devise to implement social login (Linkedin and Facebook) on a Rails4 website.

I want to be able to auto-login to user who has already logged in before on the browser (Same as facebook does: http://facebook.com)

I understand that this could be done by placing a cookie on the user with their user id and then use that on landing page to login the user.

However I feel this is such a common use case that Devise or some other Gem might already exist that does it cleanly ?

Answer (score 3):

Devise has a module [Rememberable](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Rememberable), which allows you to remember a logged in user.

Just add :rememberable to the devise method in your User model.